# how to show the little circle in tooltip of highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

By default highcharts show a little circle in tooltip with its series color. How can I show this little circle in my formatter function of tooltip in highcharts?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9DvI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in the `tooltip.formatter` :

```
`<span style="color:${this.color}">●</span>`
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5qjfy18x/